# BigQuery.insert error "unknown" in server side GTM

Tags: google-bigquery, google-tag-manager

I use `BigQuery.insert` https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/api#bigquery to stream data from server side GTM to BigQuery. Everytime I try it I get the following error `[{"reason":"unknown"}]`. My server is not located in Google Cloud but in private vps. What does this error indicate? Can there be a problem with authorization? I would imagine that in this case error message would be a little more helpful. There is also no mention of this error in documentation.

Comment: Could you confirm if the schema of the destination BQ table aligns with the data that you're streaming?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan yes I double checked it. The schema consist of only one entry because it was just for testing. I also confirmed that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are correct and asked our dev ops to restart the server so that `/healthz` path returned `200 OK`. I don't know what else can I do. I asked guys for application logs but there's not much more there. I am not a dev op so I don't really understand how they deployed it. They use Kubernetes, that's all I know.

Comment: hi @marketergeek, your issue might need further inspection since the error is not descriptive and non reproducible. I would advice you to open a [ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/) if you have subscription or file an issue on [issuetracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list)